# Publish Website Content into Facebook Wall daily through Magento

Tags: facebook, magento, publish

I have Magento store setup. Now I already have facebook connect, follow us on facebook everything working(using iframe, app id, app key, secret). 
Now I would like to publish my website content that is products that i offer everyday on my own facebook wall. I'm running my store on Magento.
Please advise me and kindly explain me in detail as I'm really novice in that.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of modules out there that does such, here is one of them: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aheadworks/extension/1953/facebook-link

EDIT: Give this one a try then, it is free as well:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/beetailer/extension/3659/beecoder_beeshopy

Comment: Thanks for the Great Link. But what I want is that publish web content into my faceboook wall instead of publishing purchases content into user facebook wall. thanks anyway for great reply

Comment: Changed answer with a more proper link to a module with more specific needs you are looking for, plus its free ;)